# Why is "thank you" pronounced as /θaŋ kjuː/ ("thang-Q")?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, ipa

I would like to know how native speakers say “thank you”. Do they pronounce it /θaŋk juː/ or /θaŋ kjuː/?

I am Asian and I was taught in school to say /θaŋ kjuː/ but teachers didn't explain the reason. Why is "thank you" pronounced as /θaŋ kjuː/ (if it is)?

Comment: You should explain the difference you hear more clearly. For me, *Thank you* and *Thank Q* are pronounced in exactly the same way in English.

Comment: I am British and I don't say "thank q". I say "thank [very short pause] you."

Comment: Perhaps it’s a regional thing ? Anyway I’m Irish and I pronounce it same as @MichaelHarvey describes - definitely not as *thank q*! The *k* sound is separated from the *u* sound.

Comment: Americans in the South say _thank-q._

Comment: The word _thank_ is pronounced /θaŋk/, and the word _you_ is pronounced /juː/. The name of the letter Q is pronounced /kjuː/. Leaving aside possible pauses between the two words, how exactly would you expect _thank you_ to be pronounced if not /θaŋkjuː/?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey As a Brit, it may be easier for me, than you, to say 'than q'.

Comment: I'm confused. First you ask why it's pronounced as "thank q", then you ask why it's pronounced as "thank you". So "thank q" and "thank you" are the same pronunciation to you? How else would you pronounce it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you mean, but I suppose you're getting confused because of how the phrase is pronounced when spoken fast.

For a native speaker, "Thank Q" and "Thank you" are pronounced the same way. This is because the "k" sound and the "you" (i.e 'u' ) sound make a "kyuu" sound, which is also how Q is pronounced. The only way you can possibly make a distinction is if you pause in the middle.

I can't think of any good examples, but some obvious ones would be phrases like "track you." Don't know where you'd use it, but still.

Comment: Not the only way. You can reduce the _you_ to _ya_ or closer to _yaw_, as in Margaret Thatcher's fake RP. Or you can aspirate the k, then start the _you_.